NodeJS net.Socket client - Unexpected Socket Connection Closures Without Response
Context
I've designed a small program in my company that makes a socket connection with a server socket on a PLC.
How the program works :

a new socket connection is opened with the server every 10 seconds
a socket connection is made between my client program and the server socket on a PLC
a write is made as soon as the connection is initialized
in response to my write, the server socket returns a response
on receipt of the server's response, the socket connection is closed.

In the event of a successful write, an empty response from the server, an error or a timeout, I log certain information in a database, such as: connection start date, write date, datetime server response received, frame written to the server, frame sent by the server, and so on.
To do this, I use the native NodeJS module net.Socket to define a client socket and manage server responses/errors/timeouts.
Code
"use strict";

const
    net = require('net'),
    {convertToHex} = require("./services/utils"),
    {db_insert} = require("./services/db_query"),
    {log_socket_client} = require("./services/logger"),
    crypto = require("crypto"),
    cmdCommandList = {/* ... */};


let timeout_interval_socket_client = setInterval(
    () => {
        let socket_client = new net.Socket();
        socket_client.uuid = crypto.randomUUID();

        const date_start_task = new Date();
        let
            frame_input_in_hex = null,
            date_socket_write = null;

        socket_client
            .on("connect", function() {
                buf_command_automat = /* _AUTOMATE_BUFFER_COMMAND_ */;

                frame_input_in_hex = convertToHex(buf_command_automat);
                socket_client.write(buf_command_automat, function() {
                    date_socket_write = new Date();
                });
            })
            .on('data', function(message) {
                /* INSERT TO BDD MESSAGE : frame output received by socket server */
                socket_client.destroy();
            })
            .on('close', function(hadError) {
                (async() => {
                    if(socket_client.bytesWritten === 0) {
                        /* INSERT TO BDD MESSAGE : noBytesWritten */
                    }

                    if(socket_client.bytesRead === 0) {
                        /* INSERT TO BDD MESSAGE : no packet received */
                    }

                    await socket_client.destroy();
                })();
            })
            .on('error', function(error) {
                /* INSERT TO BDD error.toString()  */
                if(socket_client) socket_client.close();
            })
            .on('timeout', () => {
                /* INSERT TO BDD MESSAGE : timeout  */
                if(socket_client) socket_client.close();
            });

            
        socket_client.setTimeout(15000);
        socket_client.connect(/* _AUTOMATE_PORT_ */, /* _AUTOMATE_IP_ */);

    }, (10000)
);


process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    if(timeout_interval_socket_client) {
        clearInterval(timeout_interval_socket_client);
    }
});

Problem
And my problem is that some connections close without even getting a response from the server even though a client socket write has been made. Do you have any idea why this happens?
What I've tried

Check that it wasn't a dynamically closed socket
Try .destroy instead of .close sockets
Put ids in the sockets to check that it wasn't a side effect of setInterval

Additional information

NodeJS : v18.17.1
npm: v9.6.7
Socket timeout set to 15 seconds

